# Q-Q plots and normality: Can I use ANOVA?

Tags: normal-distribution, anova, qq-plot, psychology

I want to use an ANOVA for my analysis (2x3 design). I can decide if I can safely use parametric tests. The two samples results: Shapiro-Wilk p<.001) and Q-Q plots don't seem to be normally distributed. Should I use non-parametric tests?

I want to test the relationship between an ordinal variable (high/low and high/medium/low) and a discrete variable (score of a questionnaire) using an ANOVA (2x3 design).

Each sample has 427 participants.

[image: sample1][image: sample2]

Comment: I would feel positive about ANOVA with these results.

Answer (score 1):

On one side, keep in mind that tests like Shapiro-Wilk tend to provide significant results even for small deviations if the sample you have is large enough. It is a good thing that you provided the Q-Q plots, which, as you mentioned, seem to deviate from normality (although this is always somewhat subject).

On the other hand, and more precisely related to your question: I would avoid using ANOVA. The fact that you have discrete data violates one of the assumptions of ANOVA, even though the impact of this is dependent on your variance and the number of counts. I would try to find a more suitable test. See similar case here: [Two-way ANOVA with count data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130393/two-way-anova-with-count-data)

Comment: I disagree. Questionnaire score seems to have several different values. However, access to the original data would allow a better answer.

Comment: I am interested in your point. Could you please elaborate? What exactly makes you go for ANOVA, given the discrete nature of the score of the questionnaire?

Comment: All variables are discrete. Some are more discrete than others. Human adult height measured in cm is discrete in practice, but continuous in principle. If questionnaire score varied only from say 0 to 10, I would be a little queasy about using it, but my guess is that the number of possible scores is larger. Like you I have only the quantile plots as evidence.

Comment: ANOVA makes no assumptions about discreteness of the response variable.